# Duplicate data analysis using Unix shell

Tags: shell, unix

I want to print or show only duplicate data between files. Suppose I have 3 files and their data are as follows:

```
file 1: man
file 2: man
file 3: female
```

I want to print using any shell script or awk command or any Unix shell command to show only duplicate data in the files. Like the word "man"" is duplicate in the files so i want only man to be printed on the screen. And when I do the analysis in any order like 1 2 3 or 2 3 1 or 1 3 2 only duplicate data should print on the screen.

Comment: Hint:-  awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;b[$2]++;next} a[$1] || b[$1] {print $1} a[$2] || b[$2]{print $2}' 3 2 1 (but this is not printing the duplicate data when I am starting with 3), (it is printing duplicate data when I am starting with 1 or 2.

Comment: No this is not doing what i want. this is printing all the data from all the files..

Comment: After posting my answer I realize that your question is a bit ambiguous, do you only want to print duplicates shared among several files or should duplicate lines within the same file also be printed?

Comment: You haven't answered my question but I added another solution which only prints duplicate lines shared by at least two files nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

```
sort | uniq -c | awk '$1 > 1'
```

Comment: This will also print the count and thus skew the output which might or might not be a problem for OP. `uniq` comes with `-d` so there is really no reason to do it like that, but one could do the whole thing with *just* `awk` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Testdata:

```
$ grep . file*
file1:man
file2:man
file3:female
file4:duplicate
file4:duplicate
```

## Printing *all* duplicate lines

### 1. Using `sort` + `uniq`

```
$ cat file* | sort | uniq -d
duplicate
man
```

### 2. Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{a[$0]++} END{for (i in a) if (a[i] > 1) print i}' file*
duplicate
man
```

## Printing only duplicate lines shared by two or more files

### 1. Using `GNU awk 4+`

```
$ cat t.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGINFILE { delete a }
{ a[$0]++ }
ENDFILE { for (i in a) b[i]++ }
END     { for (i in b) if (b[i] > 1) print i }
```

.

```
$ ./t.awk file*
man
```